# Discretizar una columna de dataframe de string a números

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

¿Cómo se hace para pasar de string a números una columna de un dataframe? Es decir, quiero discretizar una columna para luego poder hacer diferentes cálculos cómo por ejemplo saber que correlaciones tiene esa columna.

Yo hice lo siguiente,

```
df.loc[df['out'] == 'unknown', "out"] = 0
df.loc[df['out'] == 'failure', "out"] = 1
df.loc[df['out'] == 'other'  , "out"] = 2
df.loc[df['out'] == 'success', "out"] = 3
```

Pero imagino que `pandas` ya debe tener su propia función ya que en este caso es viable ya que solo eran 4 variables pero en muchos otros esta opción no lo será.

Por lo tanto mi pregunta es ¿cómo convierto a numerica una columna de strings?

¡Salud y gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas tiene un tipo de datos llamado [`category`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html), pensado para estos casos en los que en una columna sólo puede haber ciertos valores, típicamente etiquetados con diferentes identificadores (en tu caso `success`, `failure`, etc.) que es más eficiente en términos de memoria que el uso de strings.

Tu columna en cambio, aunque conceptualmente tiene datos categóricos, en realidad no los tiene para pandas porque sus elementos son strings. Pandas tiene un método para convertir strings en categorías. Una vez lo tienes así, permite obtener diferentes representaciones para esas categorías (representación textual o numérica, por ejemplo).

Voy a construir un dataframe aleatorio para ejemplificarlo:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

categorias = ["unknown", "failure", "other", "success"]

data = { "out": [random.choice(categorias) for _ in range(20)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.out.head())
```

```
0    success
1    success
2      other
3    success
4    success
Name: out, dtype: object
```

Fíjate al final, en el `dtype: object`, que es el tipo que pandas asigna a lo que no son números, ni categorías. En concreto, en este caso, son strings.

Para obtener esa columna como "categorias" en vez de cadenas:

```
r = df.out.astype("category")
print(r.head())
```

```
0    success
1    success
2      other
3    success
4    success
Name: out, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): [failure, other, success, unknown]
```

Aunque la salida sigue siendo textual, los elementos de esa columna son ahora `dtype: category` (y al final te muestra los cuatro posibles valores de la categoría, que ha detectado automáticamente).

Ahora podemos operar sobre esa columna de diferentes formas. Por ejemplo `r.str` permite acceder a los elementos como cadenas, para usar cosas del estilo de `r.str.contains("o")`, por ejemplo, para obtener una columna de booleanos que serán `True` para los casos en que la categoria contenga una `o`.

Lo que te interesa a tí es acceder a los elementos como categorías (`r.cat`) para extraer su código, que es un entero (`r.cat.codes`). En el siguiente ejemplo lo asigno a otra columna del dataframe, pero tú podrías asignarlo si quieres a la misma `out`:

```
df["code"] = r.cat.codes
print(df.head())
```

```
       out  code
0  success     2
1  success     2
2    other     1
3  success     2
4  success     2
```

Answer (score 3):

Para ofrecer una solución alternativa a la ya propuesta, yo te diría de hacerlo con **one-hot encoding**, ¿por qué? Porque al final, cuando creas un modelo para establecer relaciones entre los distintos valores de un atributo, la mayoría da más importancia a los valores más grandes y, lo que haces con el encoder (asignar un número natural a cada categoría), es precisamente dar más valor a las categorías que obtengan un valor más alto.

One-hot consiste en una matriz unidimensional de tamaño *n*, siendo *n* el número de clases del atributo en cuestión, es decir, que si tenemos 4 atributos, como los de tu ejemplo: unknown, failure, other y success, los valores para cada uno de los elementos serían los siguientes con one-hot:

- Unknown = [1,0,0,0]
- failure = [0,1,0,0]
- other = [0,0,1,0]
- success = [0,0,0,1]

De ésta manera hacemos que cada clase posea el mismo valor y, al mismo tiempo, categorizarlas.

Pandas ofrece una función llamada **pandas.get_dummies()** que crea automáticamente un dataframe con ésta codificación, por poner un ejemplo práctico:

```
import pandas as pd

#Creo un dataframe con 6 ejemplos
df = pd.DataFrame(data = ['unknown', 'failure', 'other', 'success','failure', 'other' ], columns = ['out'])

print(df)

       out
0  unknown
1  failure
2    other
3  success
4  failure
5    other

#Utilizo pandas.get_dummies para obtener el one-hot encoding del dataframe
print(pd.get_dummies(df))

   out_failure  out_other  out_success  out_unknown
0            0          0            0            1
1            1          0            0            0
2            0          1            0            0
3            0          0            1            0
4            1          0            0            0
5            0          1            0            0
```

¡Espero que te ayude! Siempre está bien tener alternativas.